# openmp libraries in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, openmp, intel-fortran

What are the OpenMP libraries in Visual Studio 2017?  I am migrating code from Visual Studio 2008 and get unresolved externals for some of my applications.  I searched for VCOMP.LIB and VCOMPD.lib and find them in the old compiler libraries but they are missing for the new installation.  Have they been renamed or did I just not install the correct parts of Visual Studio 2017.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: After further work I discovered the actual issue may be in Intel Visual FORTRAN 2018 as the program's in question are mixed language and compile and link fine in 64-bit but not in 32-bit.  I checked the libraries being used, libiomp5.lib is searched and the functions the linker defines as unresolved are there.  64-bit finds the but 32-bit does not.  This all worked in VS2008 so I am confused.

Comment: OpenMP is in your compiler. Visual Studio is only a text editor and project management software (+ many more features). It does not change the compiler.

Comment: Intel compilers will not install correctly without Microsoft c++.  Thus a valid installation would include both openmp libraries,  although the Intel one supports both the Intel and Microsoft compilers.

Comment: I figured out the problem, the libraries are all present.  For Intel Fortran the library is libiomp5.lib.  The issue was a calling convention problem that worked for 64-bit but not 32-bit.  I had to use INTERFACE statements to prototype a couple OpenMP calls in FORTRAN and got it working.  Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 0):

VS2017 should not have done anything to OpenMP other than change the library directory structure.  You shouldn't be making your application require changes to accommodatesuch differences, in particular since Microsoft OpenMP has had no updates since VS2005 (OpenMP 2.0).  In my installation I see Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\amd64\vcomp[d].lib.  You should get these with any VS installation which specifies C++ support with an appropriate SDK.